# How to delete multiple columns in the QGIS processing model?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, modelling

I made the union of two tables I want to erase some columns. How can I do this automatically?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Refactor Fields, as part of your model.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 3, there is the [**Drop field(s)**](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#drop-field-s) tool which can be added to your model and allows you to select which fields you want to keep or drop.