# Dropping all fields exept one with QGIS 3 Model Builder

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler, delete

Is there a way to remove all but one of the fields in the attribute table (with a pre-known name) using QGIS 3 Model Builder?

The problem is, I don't want to include all of these names in the model builder (besides they might not be known beforehand).

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315033/how-to-delete-multiple-columns-in-the-qgis-processing-model/315205#315205

Comment: I haven't used the model builder but instead of dropping an unknown number of columns could you just select the column you want to keep into a new table?

Comment: @MBain The problem is that you can't do this in the model builder because you don't know the field names before you start processing.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the noise :)

Comment: Added a new pull request to avoid using third-party scripts: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/39114

Comment: Could you explain - with some example fields - what you're trying to do? From your original question, seems like @MBain's comment would work since you say you do have a '*pre-known name*' to select, and just want to drop the other fields?

Comment: @Simbamangu I have a lot of fields in a layer and I want to delete all of them except the selected ones (and I want to do this in the model builder / designer). See this animation how it will work in further QGIS updates: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20655102/94802301-d41b4480-0400-11eb-8fd7-13d609ba5427.gif

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the algorithm 'Refactor Fields' in the Model Builder.

[image]

For 'source expression' and 'name' in the Refactor dialog, use the field name that you know from your input; that will be the only field remaining in the output vector.

You can use the 'load fields from template layer' option to get correctly-entered fields, then use the 'delete selected field' button to remove the ones you don't want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind playing around with Python a bit - you could export the model to a Python script using the option *Export as Script Algorithm...* in the *Processing Modeler* window.

Then you could inject this piece of code and run the exported script.
Of course then you can easily implement your logic of passing the field name dynamically.

```py
#INPUT - fields to remain
fieldsToRemain = ["id", "temp_id"]

#vlayer is a QgsVectorLayer object
fields = vlayer.fields()
print([f.name() for f in fields])

fieldsToDelete = []
for field in [f for f in fields if not f.name() in fieldsToRemain]:
    idx = fields.indexFromName(field.name())
    fieldsToDelete.append(idx)

vlayer.startEditing()
vlayer.deleteAttributes(fieldsToDelete)
vlayer.commitChanges()

#only the desired fields are left
print([f.name() for f in vlayer.fields()])
```